# Can insertBefore insert HTML tags?

Tags: javascript

In the script below, i am inserting some code at the beginning of a DIV.

```
    var mydiv = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    var mycontent = document.createElement("p");
    mycontent.insertBefore(document.createTextNode("Hello <b>World</b><br><bR>"));
    mydiv.insertBefore(mycontent,mydiv.firstChild);
```

On my website, the code is inserted as text and the HTML formatting is ignored. Does anyone know how to have code inserted into a DIV using javascript?

Comment: if you got correct answer, please accept it ( click the checkmark under vote buttons)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot insert tags, you can insert only DOM nodes. DOM nodes can be text nodes or element nodes (or a few others that you almost certainly don't care about).

The distinction is important since you can insert `<div></div>` but not `<div>`.

To create an element:

```
var myElement = document.createElement('div');
```

Your particular example:

```
var myContent = document.createElement('p');
myContent.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hello'));
var bold = document.createElement('b'); // Please don't use presentational elements in 2012
bold.appendChild(document.createTextNode('World');
myContent.appendChild(bold);
myContent.appendChild(document.createElement('br')); // Please don't use line breaks as margin/padding substitutes
myContent.appendChild(document.createElement('br')); 
mydiv.insertBefore(mycontent,mydiv.firstChild);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use in conjunction with an element and `innerHTML` for a simple solution:

```
var mydiv = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var mycontent = document.createElement("p");
mycontent.innerHTML = 'Hello <b>World</b><br><bR>';
mydiv.insertBefore(mycontent, mydiv.firstChild);
```

Answer (score 0):

why not

```
var mydiv = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var mycontent = document.createElement("p");
mycontent.innerHTML = "Hello <b>World</b><br><bR>";
mydiv.insertBefore(mycontent,mydiv.firstChild);​
```